# Applozic crashes with cordova google analytics plugin in Android

Tags: android, applozic

I am using Applozic for messaging on Android.
https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Cordova-PhoneGap-Chat-Plugin

I have added cordova google analytics plugin.

The applozic.login is successful, but the app closes and unable to launch applozic.launchChat on Android.

Comment: Can you add the error logs ?

Comment: I have logged the issue and its details here, https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Cordova-PhoneGap-Chat-Plugin/issues/10

Comment: This was an issue with google play service version mismatch we have updated play services library to latest